# Is it safe to run animations in a useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I've started introducing some React hooks into my code, specifically the `useEffect` and I can't seem to find out whether what I'm doing is considered safe or not. Essentially I'm running animations on the DOM within the hook, and I want to ensure that's not going to break any DOM snapshots for example.

Here's an example, I've modified from my full example to try and be concise to illustrate what's happening:

```
export function GrowingCircle(props) {

  const root = useRef(null);          // This is the root element we draw to

  // The actual rendering is done whenever the data changes
  useEffect(() => {

    const radius = props.width / 2;

    d3.select(root.current)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("r", radius);

  }, [props.width]);

  return (
      <svg width={props.width} height="100%">
        <circle ref={root} cx="0" cy="0" r="0" fill="red" />
      </svg>
    );
}
```

The part I'm concerned about is the `.transition()` is going to run frequent updates on the DOM for 1 second, and I'm unsure if that's going to mess up the react rendering?

---

A follow up question (as often we don't have control of the animation rendering like in this example). Would the following where the `circle` is no longer within the JSX change things?

```
export function GrowingCircle(props) {

  const root = useRef(null);          // This is the root element we draw to

  // The actual rendering is done whenever the data changes
  useEffect(() => {

    const radius = props.width / 2;

    d3.select(root.current)
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("r", radius);

  }, [props.width]);

  return (
      <svg ref={root} width={props.width} height="100%">
      </svg>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been in your same scenario, to give you a short answer, since there is no real D3 - React implementation, you need to draw your own boundaries of imperative versus declarative rendering. However in both your example, you aren't really breaking any rules.

In your second example you're passing the reins to D3 to do the full rendering, while React simple keeps a ref to the top-level svg element. While in your first example, you're rendering a single circle, and only managing its transition with D3.

However in the 1st example, since it looks like you never change anything in the DOM after declaration, React should geneally never interfere. Here's a third example achieving something similar to what you wrote :

```
export function GrowingCircle(props) {

  const root = useRef(null);          // This is the root element we draw to

  const [radius,setRadius] = useState(0);  //initial radius value

  useEffect(() => {

    d3.select(root.current)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("r", props.width / 2)
      .on("end", () => {setRadius(props.width / 2)});   //this is necessary

  }, [props.width]);

  return (
      <svg width={props.width} height="100%">
        <circle ref={root} cx="0" cy="0" r={radius} fill="red" />
      </svg>
    );
}
```

I've ran into a similar problem myself, and from what I understood, during the transition d3 acts on your desired value directly, causing it not to trigger react's re-render mechanism. But once it's done, I'm assuming it directly tries to act on the radius value, and your circle snaps back to its 0 original value. So you simply add an .on('end') event to update its state, and there you have it!

I feel like this is as close as it gets to the react way, where d3 only selects elements rendered based on react state.

Comment: Thanks - I think my main concern is what's happening to DOM diffing that React does under the hood. In the first example I could see React wanting to reset the radius of the circle based on the snapshot for example...

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements rendered by React can be modified. **However** if React needs to re-render because the Virtual DOM doesn't match with the current DOM (the one that React has as the current) it might replace the modified parts, and changes made out of React could be lost.

**React modifies the necessary parts** so modifications might remain if React only modified a part of the element or they might be removed. So, as far as I understand, we can not trust modifications will remain. Only if we knew for sure the Component output will not change after the custom modifications.

My suggestion is to use React to keep track of any change:

- Use `useState` and `useEffect` to modify `style` properties.
- Use CSS classes and handle the animation using CSS.
- Use an animation library which is made for React (take a look at [Framer motion](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/)).

Comment: Hmm, thanks Alvaro. In this case I'm using a D3 library and it's not possible for me to give control over to React for those parts of the DOM as I don't have access to stop the rendering. If the `circle` were added to the DOM in the `useEffect`so it's not covered under the JSX part - would that change the state of play?

Comment: I've added a bit to my question to that effect to help illustrate.

Comment: @Ian I made some tests with a similar scenario as the one you have and it seems that extra child elements remain after modifying the child in React. I guess React tries to do the mimimum/most effective operation to update the Component output: modify the attribute; append a child rather than modify the whole innerHTML... So that is probably why it seems to be ok. But as I said in the answer I dont think we can rely on it. Lets see if someone with good understanding of the internals can give a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro I appreciate the effort and will be +1'ing. I might reach out to Dan Abramov to get his thoughts as I've found it quite unclear from the docs.

Comment: @Ian you are welcome, Im certainly no expert. It would be great to actually get an answer from him or someone from the team.